# MAAS - UI has only Nodes link and nodes stuck in commissioning status - maas in vagrant box

Tags: maas, vagrant

I want to install a maas server and a test server using vagrant with virtual box as provider and want to use the maas to do the power cycle for the test server.

I have installed ubuntu MAAS in a vagrant box using virtual box as provider.
But on accessing the web UI, only the nodes link is visible and no clusters/zones links are present.
Also getting the boot images missing warning.

I tried the maas-import-pxe-files in the box, but still the warning persists and no other links in UI.

I tried to setup a node for the test server and is getting stuck in commissioning status.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

I found out the issue.
The vagrant box I used for installing MAAS was precise32.box.
I used another 64-bit box ubuntu/trusty64 and installed maas services.

All MAAS links appeared in web UI and I could import images too.

To setup nodes, we should do the following:

1. Create a new network without dhcp enabled.
2. Configure the maas dhcp to point to the above subnet.
3. On creating the nodes, enable the above network.

This way, the nodes can get IPs from MAAS-DHCP service.